# Why negative value comes for long after multiplication?

Tags: java, long-integer

Why this code in java gives negative value?

```
    long ttt = (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 26);
    System.out.println(ttt);
```

Result which comes as on eclipse console `-2134967296`?

Anything silly I am doing, may be it crossed int range I guess?

Comment: You're multiplying integers and then assigning it to a long. Append `l` or `L` to a value to turn them into longs while multiplying (`long ttt = (60L * 60L * 1000L * 24L * 25L);`).

Answer (score 9):

Because `60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 25` overflows in the `int` range.

Make one of them a `long` so that promotion occurs

```
60L * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 25
```